# How to get size of composable in a custom Modifier?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to get the size of a Composable in a Custom Modifier?

I am using `composed` lambda in my custom Modifier.

Providing a minified code for reference,

```
@Composable
fun CustomModifierDemo() {
    val sizeInDp = 100.dp
    val sizeInPx = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        100.dp.toPx()
    }
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(sizeInDp)
            .customAnim(
                sizeInPx = sizeInPx,
            )
            .background(Color.Red)
    )
}

fun Modifier.customAnim(
    sizeInPx: Float,
): Modifier {
    return composed {
        val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(
            label = "",
        )
        val translateAnimation = transition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0F,
            targetValue = sizeInPx,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(
                    durationMillis = 600,
                    delayMillis = 0,
                    easing = LinearEasing,
                ),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse,
            ),
            label = "",
        )
        val translateAnimationInDp = with(LocalDensity.current) {
            translateAnimation.value.toDp()
        }
        this.then(
            Modifier
                .offset(
                    x = translateAnimationInDp,
                    y = 0.dp,
                )
        )
    }
}
```

Here, `sizeInPx` is passed as a parameter to the modifier as it is a hardcoded value, how to do the same without having such a hard-coded value?

I want the logic to be within the custom modifier if possible. I want to avoid passing the size to the custom Modifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get size from `DrawScope` or `CacheDrawScope`. Using `Modifier.drawWithCache`

```
/**
 * Draw into a [DrawScope] with content that is persisted across
 * draw calls as long as the size of the drawing area is the same or
 * any state objects that are read have not changed. In the event that
 * the drawing area changes, or the underlying state values that are being read
 * change, this method is invoked again to recreate objects to be used during drawing
 *
 * For example, a [androidx.compose.ui.graphics.LinearGradient] that is to occupy the full
 * bounds of the drawing area can be created once the size has been defined and referenced
 * for subsequent draw calls without having to re-allocate.
 *
 * @sample androidx.compose.ui.samples.DrawWithCacheModifierSample
 * @sample androidx.compose.ui.samples.DrawWithCacheModifierStateParameterSample
 * @sample androidx.compose.ui.samples.DrawWithCacheContentSample
 */
fun Modifier.drawWithCache(
    onBuildDrawCache: CacheDrawScope.() -> DrawResult
) = composed(
    inspectorInfo = debugInspectorInfo {
        name = "drawWithCache"
        properties["onBuildDrawCache"] = onBuildDrawCache
    }
) {
    val cacheDrawScope = remember { CacheDrawScope() }
    this.then(DrawContentCacheModifier(cacheDrawScope, onBuildDrawCache))
}
```

you get inside scope while translating drawing inside onDrawWithContent with

```
fun Modifier.customAnim(): Modifier = composed {

    var size by remember {
        mutableStateOf(0f)
    }

    val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(
        label = "",
    )

    val translateAnimation = transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0F,
        targetValue = size,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(
                durationMillis = 600,
                delayMillis = 0,
                easing = LinearEasing,
            ),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse,
        ),
        label = "",
    )

    this.then(
        Modifier
            .drawWithCache {
                size = this.size.width
                onDrawWithContent {
                    translate(left = translateAnimation.value) {
                        this@onDrawWithContent.drawContent()
                    }
                }
            }
    )
}
```

You can sure, draw with Modifier.drawWithContent as well but when allocations are to be made once, of course setting same value has no impilication for mutableState, and to get size before starting drawing Modifier.drawWithCache suits better.

Also other options to get size of a Composable inside Modifier are `Modifier.onSizeChanged`, `Modifier.onPlaced`, `Modifier.onGloballyPoisitioned` and `Modifier.pointerInput`.

Comment: Thank You, `onSizeChanged` works well for my actual use-case which was to set the background brush, and `drawWithCache` helps with use-cases like animation where translations were required.

Comment: You are welcome @Abhimanyu. Wouldn't Modifier.drawWithCache suit better for creating a Brush only once as described in its kdoc?